# Web <table> to Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have been developing a webpage that allows users to search for items in a database based on several filters/criteria. One of the requirements is the ability to export this data into a spreadsheet (excel). I have created a really simple method so far utilizing a CSV file.

```
//get model...
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

//First line for column names
sw.WriteLine("col1,col2,col3");

foreach (DataType i in model)
{
    sw.WriteLine(string.Format({0},{1},{2},
                                i.data1,
                                i.data2,
                                i.data3));
}

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv");
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Response.Write(sw);
Response.End();
```

Simple enough, but I desire more control over the formatting of my spreadsheet. After some searching, I found these documents: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) & [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx) which describe a type of XML accepted by excel. I'd like to learn more about this document type, but documentation seems to be lacking. Nowhere in the wiki link is there details about the format, and there are no examples in the MSDN article. I can't cross reference the two because they seem to use different versions (`ss: workbook` vs `workbook`). Heck, I can't even find out what the `ss:`,`x:`, and `c:` prefix stands for. Additionally, the MSDN article is for Office 2003 and I can't seem to find a more recent version.

Perhaps I am looking up the wrong thing all together; is there a more modern way to achieve my goal? Sources are appreciated.

Comment: since you're dealing with asp, you could just invoke Excel via COM and build a real spreadsheet, instead of messing around with csv or html.

Comment: It will not be pretty, but it will be the most straightforward approach.

Comment: @Marc-B COM-automation isn't supported on the server.

Comment: @Jeff try EPPlus from CodePlex, it's 100% .NET.  It can generate XLSX files for you.

Comment: @Chris Seems promising. I will check it out... My company has strict policies on libraries/frameworks we are allowed to use. While I do research into EPPlus, do you have any thoughts regarding using my web server to generate XML?

Comment: @Jeff you can try the spreadsheetML, but you'll need to figure out the namespaces and no telling how they change as you add more data/columns.  In the interest of time and frustration, keep it as simple as possible.  I would generate the XML and XSD by hand.  You can create a simple template and reuse it.  If you're using Excel because of users, remember Excel can reverse engineer almost anything you can generate by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but EPPlus can generate a xlsx worksheet for you.  I wanted to provide you a sample instead of just saying, "here use this".

Here is a sample taken from here: [EPPlus Source Listing](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6852709011e3#EPPlusWebSample/GetSample.aspx.cs)

```
ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage();

var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

//First line for column names
ws.Cells["A1"] = "col1";
ws.Cells["A2"] = "col2";
ws.Cells["A3"] = "col3";

int row = 2;

foreach (DataType i in model)
{
    //I don't know you data model, I'm guessing

    //row, col
    ws.Cells[row, 1] = i.data1);
    ws.Cells[row, 2] = i.data2);
    ws.Cells[row, 3] = i.data3);

    row++;
}

pck.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=YouNameGoesHere.xlsx");
```

Hopefully this is along the lines of what you need.